# Given x ⊕ x =5,x ⊕ (y ⊕ z) = (x ⊕ y)+z-5 what is 2009 ⊕ 1949

Tags: replacement, rule, algebra

There is an operation "⊕" that satisfies

1. $x ⊕ x =5$
2. $x ⊕ (y ⊕ z) = (x ⊕ y)+z-5$

what is 2009 ⊕ 1949?
I think it is feasible to solve with Mathematica, but my code doesn't give a useful result, am i missing something?

```
Clear["`*"];
f[2009, 1949] //. {f[x_, y_] :> f[x, f[y, z]] - z + 5, f[x_, x_] :> 5,
  f[x_, f[y_, y_]] :> y + 5}
```

Comment: With `CirclePlus[2009, 1949]` you can get the exact writing that your question has. [`CirclePlus`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CirclePlus.html) is an operator with no built-in meaning.

Comment: `f[2009, 1949]==65`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that you can only find out by exploring substitutions. Doing a bit of trial in the 2nd condition I found a couple of relations that can solve the problem by substituting z for y, and then substituting both y and z for x.

```
x ⊕(y⊕z) == (x⊕y) + z - 5 /. 
  z -> y //. CirclePlus[x_, x_] :> 5
(* x⊕5 == -5 + y + x⊕y *)
x ⊕(y⊕z) == (x⊕y) + z - 5 /. {y ->
     x, z -> x} //. CirclePlus[x_, x_] :> 5
(* x⊕5 == x *)
```

From the first relation we can easily get that `x⊕y==5 - y + x⊕5`; from the second sit is clear that this expression can be further simplified into `x⊕y==5 - y + x`.

Finally using this as a single rule applied to 2009 and 1949

```
2009⊕1949 /. {x_⊕y_ :> x + 5 - y}
(*65*)
```

This is the result that Ulrich Neumann has mentioned in the comments, and `⊕` is the operator that Roman has suggested in the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible methods to try. Here is one that I
came up with in a few minutes without knowing the answer. It
depends on using a range of substitutions which may give the
answer and it is possible that it may be improved.

First, I decided to use `f` instead of `CirclePlus` and `V`
instead of $5$ for clarity and no loss of generality. The two
properties of the operation are given to us. I used the the
first as a replacement rule because it is so obvious and
simple. I used the second as a template and substituted the
three variables with a range of substitutions. My code:

```
Select[ Flatten[ Table[
   f[i, f[j, k] == f[i, j] + k - V /. f[x_, x_] :> V,
   {i, {x}}, {j, {x,y}}, {k, {x,y,z,V}}], 2],
   FreeQ[#, f[_, f[_, _]]]&]
```

returns the result

```
{f[x, V] == x, f[x, V] == -V + y + f[x, y]}
```

and combining the two equalities it is immediate that
$f(x,y) = x - y + V.$.